# AssertionError: 'LeadViewSet' should either include a `serializer_class` attribute, or override the `get_serializer_class()` method

Tags: django, rest, postman, assertion

I want to perform get and post operations in the Postman. Unfortunately, I get an assertion error. Following is the error and code.

http://localhost:8000/api/lead/

**Error I am getting is:**

```
AssertionError at /api/lead/
'LeadViewSet' should either include a `serializer_class` attribute, or override the `get_serializer_class()` method.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/lead/
Django Version: 3.1.4
Exception Type: AssertionError
Exception Value:    
'LeadViewSet' should either include a `serializer_class` attribute, or override the `get_serializer_class()` method.
```

**Here is the code.**

**api.py**

```
from lead.models import Lead

from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions

from .serializers import LeadSerializer

#Lead Viewset

class LeadViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Lead.objects.all()

    permission_classes = [

     permissions.AllowAny

    ]

serializer_class = LeadSerializer
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from lead.models import Lead

#Lead Serializer

class LeadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:

        model = Lead

        fields = '__all__'
```

**urls.py**

```
from rest_framework import routers

from .api import LeadViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register('api/lead', LeadViewSet, 'lead')

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Comment: Not sure if it is a mistake you made posting here or that the same mistake is also in your code. `serializer_class = LeadSerializer` is not within the `LeadViewSet` class

Comment: Great! That was it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I think in api.py file the last line i.e.

> serializer_class = LeadSerializer

is not properly indented inside the class, hence the class is not able to identify the serializer class for it.